# JQuery doesn't load in time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So I'm trying to run some jQuery code on my ASP webpage, but I keep getting the lovely `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error. So for some reason my jQuery is not initialised yet, but can't figure out why.

[image: Image of my source files being loaded in. Default.aspx loads first, somewhere at the bottom jquery-ui.min.js is loaded as well with status 200]

As you can see, both my `Default.aspx` and my `jquery-ui.min.js` files are being loaded with status code 200.

In my `Default.aspx` I have the following code:

```
window.onload = function (e) {
    console.log("this works 1", this);
};

window.onload = function (e) {
    console.log("this works 2", $(this));
};

(function ($) {
    console.log("this works 3", this);
});

(function ($) {
    console.log("this works 4", $(this));
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("getting desperate now");
});

var something = $(this);
console.log(something);
```

The result is that the code breaks at the following:
`$(document).ready(function(){` because it doesn't recognize the $. He won't show a log in the console, because it breaks on the $ symbol.

Next test I did, was the following:

```
window.onload = function (e) {
    console.log("this works 1", this);
};
window.onload = function (e) {
    console.log("this works 2", $(this));
};
(function ($) {
    console.log("this works 3", this);
});
(function ($) {
    console.log("this works 4", $(this));
});
```

This time the code doesn't break, but no log was added to the console either. So for some reason my `window.onload` or `(function ($) { });` doesn't work either.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to reference jQuery before it is parsed.... Your script that uses jQuery needs to be after the jQuery core reference.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did. Ignore me

Comment: Can you show your ASPX (the section with script tags)?

Comment: could this be coming from jquery-datatables? perhaps it needs jquery too and the error is from there

Comment: Where is your code being executed? It's still possible to get the `$ is undefined` error if you run your script before including jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

As I see your resource screenshot, I can tell that your code is loaded and executed BEFORE jquery is loaded.

So all you have to do is change the order you load your files. I'm not an ASP builder but go to the place where you define your scripts. And put JQUERY in front of the other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has to be referenced before you reference any JavaScript file which uses the jQuery Syntax (e.g. $)

1. Reference your jQuery.min.js
2. Then your JavaScript File